# Building monorepo babel-transpiled node JS application with dependencies

Tags: node.js, babeljs, monorepo

I am working on a project that is hosted as a monorepo.  For simplification purposes let's say that inside there are three self-explanatory packages: `server`, a `webapp` client and `library`. The directory structure would be something like the following:

```
the-project 
  packages
    server
      src
    webapp
      src
    library
      src
```

All packages employ flow type notation, use a few >ES5 features and, for this reason, go through babel transpilation. The key difference is that transpilation of the `webapp` package is done via webpack, whereas `server` employs a gulp task that triggers script transpilation through the `gulp-babel` package. `library` is transpiled automatically when `web` is built.

Now, the problem I have is that for `server` to build, babel requires `library` to be built first and its `package.json` to specify its (built) main JS source file so its transpiled artifacts can be included.  As you can imagine, this would quickly become problematic if the project were to contain multiple libraries that are actively being developed (which it does), as all would require building, including any dependent packages (like `server` in this simple case).

As an attempt to overcome this annoyance, I initially thought of using webpack to build the server, which would take care of including whatever dependencies it requires into a bundle, but I ran into issues as apparently webpack is not meant to be used on node JS applications.

What strategies are available for building a node JS application requiring Babel transpilation, such that the application's source files as well as any dependencies are built transparently and contained in a single output directory?

---

**Annex A**

Simplified gulp task for transpilation of scripts, as employed by `server`.

```
return gulp
  .src([`src/**/*.js`], { allowEmpty: true })
  .pipe(babel({ sourceMap: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

As can be seen above, only `server`'s own source files are included in the task.  If `src` were to be changed to also include `library`, the task would emit the dependencies' artifacts in `server`'s own output directory and any `require('library')` statements within would attempt to locate the built artifacts in `packages/library` and not `packages/server/dist`, thus resulting in import failures.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure what your server is doing.  If it is doing a database connection or some calculations then I would not recommend it to be built by `webpack`.  Whereas If your server is just doing Server-Side Rendering and making some API calls to other servers then I would recommend it to be bundled using `webpack`.

A lot of projects follow this philosophy. For example, you can take a look at something similar, I have done in one of my personal projects [[Blubus]](https://github.com/AjayPoshak/blubus). Specifically, you might be interested in [webpack-server-config](https://github.com/AjayPoshak/blubus/blob/master/webpack.server.js). And also you can take a look at how big projects like [spectrum](https://github.com/withspectrum/spectrum) does it.